# Running an android exploit on Emulator

Tags: android, c++, android-emulator, ddms, exploit

I want to run this exploit [cve-2014-7920-7921](https://github.com/laginimaineb/cve-2014-7920-7921)([from here)](https://bits-please.blogspot.ca/2016/01/android-privilege-escalation-to.html?showComment=1510538511725#c2593845067243160498) on Emulator. I am new to Android and after searching on google I did like this:
I compiled android source code 4.3 and then run the [build.sh](https://github.com/laginimaineb/cve-2014-7920-7921/blob/master/build.sh) script of this exploit. It is compiled successfully and after runing emulator I can see that it is working with the android source which I compiled. But I don't know how I can figure out that this exploit has run and worked! It has several `printf` in its code that I think they print to `/dev/null` so I put some logs using 
`__android_log_write(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "mytag", "Helllllooooooooooo\n");`
and used *Dalvik Debug Monitor(ddms)* to show the logs. But this log didn't appear. On the other hand I heard that security patches are already applied even to these old patches, so I'm in doubt that this exploit cannot work for this reason or I haven't set up the log properly.

Comment: Impossible to answer without knowing what patches the Android source code you used has.

Comment: @m0skit0 I used this branch : `repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b android-4.3_r1`